# request is undefined in express.js

Tags: node.js, session, express, request, httprequest

I am deploying a web application with node.js 4.2.3 and express.js 4.13.3.

I use [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session) express-session module that is officially sypported by express.

My code is

`**app.js**`

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/node_modules/static-favicon/favicon.ico'));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(session({
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    secret:'HeyYouAreWatchingJakeAndAmir'
}));

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.set('multimedia', __dirname + '/public/multimedia');

app.use(user());
```

Now, `app.use(user());` uses a module that I made, by reading a book. That module is named user.js, here it is

`**user.js**`

```
var User = require('../user');
var session = require('express-session');

module.exports = function(req,res,next){
    var uid = req.session.uid;
    if(!uid) return next();
    User.get(uid, "id", function(err, user){
        if (err) return next(err);
        req.user = res.locals.user = user;
        next();
    })
}
```

`User` contains some functions, such as `User.get` and if there is user id (`=uid`) , then a user is logged in and it passes the user to the session, so it can be availiable to every request.

When I hit `npm start` I get

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\awesome\lib\middleware\user.js:5
        var uid = req.session.uid;
                     ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'session' of undefined
    at module.exports (C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\awesome\lib\middleware\user
.js:5:15)
```

So, `req` is undefined?

I dont know how to proceed to debug this, please help me fix this.

The book is "Node.js in Action" by Mike Cantelon, Marc Harter, T.J. Holowaychuk and Nathan Rajlich, ©2014 by Manning Publications, chapter 9.1.2 to 9.1.4

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll want to pass `user` itself rather than invoking it.

```
app.use(user);
```

Your `app` will then be able to invoke it later while processing an active request.

---

The reason `req` is `undefined` is because, by including the extra parenthesis, you're invoking `user` without any arguments.

```
user() // req = undefined, res = undefined, next = undefined
```

And, instead providing its `return` value to `app.use()`.

```
app.use(user());

// is the same as...
var _result = user();
app.use(_result);
```

Being in the arguments to `app.use()` doesn't change that.

---

Note: Why for other middleware (`favicon`, `logger`, etc.) you do have to invoke them is because they're defined in a different manner, exporting a secondary `function` that `return`s a function for `use`.

If you had a need to, such as wanting to provide `options` to `user`, you could define it similarly.

```
// user.js
// ...

var defaultOptions = {};

module.exports = function (options) {
    options = Object.assign({}, defaultOptions, options);

    return function (req, res, next) {
        var uid = req.session.uid;
        if(!uid) return next();
        User.get(uid, "id", function(err, user){
            if (err) return next(err);
            req.user = res.locals.user = user;
            next();
        })
    };
};
```

Then, you would want to invoke the `function (options)` so that it gives `app.use()` the `function (req, res, next)`.

```
app.use(user({ setting: 'value' }));
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. At the time of writing, I thought it was something wrong with the module, not my syntax.